# Using bashrc to define an alias with loop in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

it's convenience to use alias
but in this condition

```
alias ssh.1='ssh user@192.168.0.1'
alias ssh.2='ssh user@192.168.0.2'
alias ssh.3='ssh user@192.168.0.3'
```

and I want to connect by ssh to a range 192.169.0.[0-100],

how to use variable with loop to set this

or I just define it line by line?

Comment: You should probably use a function rather than an alias. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-alias-vs-script-vs-new-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop

```
for i in {1..100}
do
   alias ssh.$i="ssh user@192.168.0.$i"
done
```